# gensim word2vec results - why non-nearby word first?

Tags: python-3.x, gensim, word2vec

```
from gensim.models import Word2Vec
model = Word2Vec(sentences = [['a','b'],['c','d']], window = 9999999, min_count=1)
model.wv.most_similar('a', topn=10)
```

Above code gives the following result:

```
[('d', 0.06363436579704285),
 ('b', -0.010543467476963997),
 ('c', -0.039232250303030014)]
```

shouldn't the 'b' ranked first, since it's the only one nearby 'a'?

Answer (score 2):

That's an interesting question, I worked with gensim a few times and would've intuitively thought the same as you, so I looked a bit closer into it.

I think first of all you need to put in a larger number of sentences, otherwise there will be next to no effect on the trained model.

The way I understand the Word2Vec model it tries to find the similarity if words by looking at their context, so it looks at the question of the surrounding words on two words are often similar. If they are, the vector representation the model learns for these two words has a low distance from each other.

Take this example:

```
import random
import numpy
from gensim.models import Word2Vec


nested_list = []
for _ in range(0, 50000):
    nested_list.append(['a', 'b'])
for _ in range(0, 50000):
    nested_list.append(['c', 'd'])
for _ in range(0, 50000):
    nested_list.append(['a', 'x'])
random.shuffle(nested_list)


model = Word2Vec(sentences=nested_list, window=9999999, min_count=1)

words = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'x']
for word in words:
    print(word, model.wv.most_similar(word, topn=10))
```

Which will return:

```
a [('c', 0.11672252416610718), ('d', 0.11632005870342255), ('x', 0.09789041429758072), ('b', 0.0978466272354126)]
b [('x', 0.999595046043396), ('c', 0.10307613760232925), ('a', 0.0978466272354126), ('d', 0.09400281310081482)]
c [('a', 0.11672253161668777), ('d', 0.11085666716098785), ('b', 0.10307613760232925), ('x', 0.0969843715429306)]
d [('a', 0.11632007360458374), ('c', 0.11085667461156845), ('x', 0.10299163311719894), ('b', 0.09400279819965363)]
x [('b', 0.9995951652526855), ('d', 0.10299164056777954), ('a', 0.09789039939641953), ('c', 0.0969843715429306)]
```

`x` and `b` often occur in a similar context (next to an `a`). All other distances between the representations have pretty much nothing noticable.

You can visualize that as well:

```
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

pca_ = PCA(n_components=2).fit_transform(numpy.array([model.wv.get_vector(v) for v in words]))
pca_x = tsne_x = [x_[0] for x_ in pca_]
pca_y = [x_[1] for x_ in pca_]
ax = plt.gca()
plt.scatter(pca_x, pca_y, alpha=0.25)
ax.set_xlim([-3, 3])
ax.set_ylim([-3, 3])
for i, name in enumerate(words):
    text = ax.annotate(name, (pca_x[i], pca_y[i]))
plt.show()
```

[image]

If you leave out `append(['a', 'x'])` loop part and remove the `x` from words, so remove the `['a', 'x']` sentences from the model training, you get basically just a random position with nothing noticable:

[image]

And if you replace the `50000` sentences per case with just `1`:

[image]

Comment: Interesting, but why wouldn't it classify 'a and b' or 'c and d'  or 'c and x' as similar?

Comment: I would assume that it only uses the context and not the word itself. So it does not look for the words nearby, it looks for words which have the same words nearby. For example, if you look up similar words for `b`, there are no noticable results, because the answer to the question "Which other words have `b`s context (a) near them?" is none. If you look up similar words for `b`, it returns something noticable, because the context (`a`) is also nearby `x`.

Comment: I think this rule of "finding substitute words" in this extreme scenario seems like it might miss out the releation of just being nearby, but in natural language that would not happen, because sentences are longer and the general terminology of a sentence already causes them to be recognized as similar.

Comment: `king` is similar to `queen` because they often occur in similar sentences, in the strongest case just replaced by each other ("The king sits on the throne."/"The queen sits on the throne."). On the other hand, `king` and `crown` do not replace each other, but they also often occur in the same context ("The king sits on his throne wearing his crown"/"The scepter and crown belong to the king."/...).

Comment: So in the case of king and queen the model learns directly from the fact that they substitute each other. In the case of king and crown the fact that they are in the same sentence does not directly cause the model to learn the similarity, but the fact that by being in same sentences also other specific words like crown are near both them still causes the model to learn their similarity.

Comment: Thanks, can you explain that based that based on the CBOW algorithm, since it's use by Word2Vec method, and it's using surrounding text to predict the current text.

Answer (score 0):

This algorithm only works wellwith large, varied training data.

There, subtleties of relative-cooccurrences can, via the push-and-pull of many contrasting examples, serve to nudge words into configurations that are useful, and generalizable to other texts using the same vocabulary. And most impressively to me, often match human intuitions about not just 'neighborhoods' of related words, but 'directions' of shades of meaning.

But none of those benefits are likely to be seen if you've got a toy-sized training set, or something synthetic that doesn't have the same sort of frequencies/cooccurrences as natural-language, or degenerately-simple usage examples. (Your 2-word texts, where words only have a single neighbor, and there's *no* chain of 'appears-close-to' relationships, however slight connecting dijoint clusters of words, are very peculiar & unnatural.)

So when trying to develop an intuitive understanding of this algorithm, I'd make sure you're always using a significant number of real natural-language texts. For example, the 100MB dataset of raw run-on text from an old Wikipedia dump known as `text8` – see the [`text8.zip` discussion about 4/5th down this page](http://mattmahoney.net/dc/textdata.html) is a reasonable basis for experimentation that can roughly reproduce things like the classic `king - man + woman = queen` result.

More generally, any time you're tempted to use `min_count=1`, you're probably making a mistake. There's a good reason the default of `min_count=5`: words with only a single (or few) usage examples won't get strong vectors via word2vec training, and further, by soaking up training time & model state, tend to *worsen* the vectors for surrounding suitably-represented words. (The common intution "keeping more data can only help" is backwards here.)

If you ever really want to try word2vec with a tiny amount of data, you *may* be able eke out a little more value with one or both of:

- Far more than the default `epochs=5` - which can help give the model more chances to learn whatever's in the thin amount of text. (But note: synthetically repeating the same few examples isn't nearly as good as true variety-of-usages that a real/large dataset could offer.)
- Far fewer than the default `vector_size=100` dimensions – which can prevent the model from being far larger than the training-data itself, an error which ensures overfitting.

Regarding that last point, note that in your original contrived test, you've got 2 texts of 2 words each – at most ~20 bytes of training data. But you're using that to train a model that learns 4 word-vectors of 100 4-byte `float` dimensions each, and also has an additional set of internal output weights equivalent to another 4 vectors of 100 4-byte `float` dimensions. That's a model of 3,200 bytes: 160X more internal state than would be necessary to store the whole training set.

That's a situation prone to extreme overfitting, where the model can just become a convoluted *expansion* of the original data, that may become arbitrarily good at modeling the idiosyncracies of the data, on the training task, without creating insights that generalize to elsewhere.

Real & effective machine learning usually looks more like *compression*: distilling large amounts of data down to a *smaller* model, which captures as much of the essence of the data, under the chosen constraints of limited size & limited methods, as possible.

Comment: Hi, can you comment on with the answer by ewz93, why wouldn't it classify 'a and b' or 'c and d' or 'c and x' as similar?

Comment: I mean based on the CBOW algorithm that has been used.

Comment: For the reasons above, why would you expect it would put them near each other? You've got too little data, that's also unlike what word2vec is usually used for. You've got a massively oversized model that can 'ace' its training task – neighbor predictions – without doing anything worthwhile positioning the words. And even if you continued down this path of deeply understanding how the algorithm does nothing interesting on tiny data & insufficient training & oversized models, then what? You could also test it on giant random texts, on which it would also do nothing interesting.

Comment: Ultimately, this is not the type/size of problem, nor desired-behavior, that motivated the creation of word2vec. Nor is it what anyone uses it for. If you want to understand word2vec, you need to use more, & more realistic, training data. If you feed it garbage, you'll get garbage out. If you want some *other* algorithm that places `a` near `b` when given this arbitrary input, you could just use a simple cooccurence lookup table. Or a document-term-matrix that models the data perfectly. It'll be 100x smaller & faster than the word2vec model!